# In Xamarin GcmListenerService is not called in background

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-messaging

I have xamarin forms android application. I am using GCM and everything is working fine, while app is in foreground. But when it is in background it stops to receive messages. `OnMessageReceived` is called only after app will go to foreground. My message looks like: `{"data":{"data2":5}, "priority" : "high","to":"/topics/updateCoordinates"}`, its data message with high priority, so according to GCM docs it should fire even in background, but it doesnt!

My `MyGcmListenerService` is:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "GetCoordinates", "Do it!");
    }
}
```

Ive tried different versions of `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` lib: 29.0.0 and latest 42.1021.1, both doesnt work in background. How could I fix that?

Added:
Just tried to make an GCMReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" }, Categories = new string[] { "com.eot.rossakor" })]
public class PushNotificationsReceiver : GcmReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    }
}
```

Same problem.

Comment: Do you subclassed and implemented the GCMReceiver broadcast receiver?

Comment: Nope. Should I?

Comment: Yes, but IMHO if you are writing a new app, or adding messaging to an existing one, you should be using FCM as a starting point as that is the new version of GCM with a "better" SDK, new features, etc..

Comment: @SushiHangover please, look at post update.
I havent found working sample of FCM, different problems in each sampe which I've tried.